# Windows Taskbar API

Tags: windows, api, taskbar

Is there any API that allows to control which icons are shown in the Windows (7) Taskbar at a given time? I would like to have the processes still running, but their icons not show up on the taskbar.

Comment: Are you using c# or c++? WinForms or WPF?

Comment: You only want the icons to be omitted? Or do you want the button to be omitted too? I use my taskbar in a mode where you see both icon and text in a single button.

Comment: I was thinking to choose the language after I had an idea how to do it :-) I'd rather use C# but I wouldn't mind do it in C++. I want the window to be hidden from view, including from the taskbar; so the button should be omitted as well.

Answer (score 4):

See the various extended window styles in [CreateWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680.aspx), and figure out which one suits your needs. (Many of them deal with taskbar items, it's not just one.) Then just set the style with `SetWindowLong`.

There's also [ITaskbarList::DeleteTab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774648.aspx), but I **really** don't recommend this for hiding your window.

Answer (score 2):

> I want the window to be hidden from view, including from the taskbar;

Hide the window. [ShowWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered creating an icon in the system tray or creating a windows [service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

You want to create the windows using [CreateWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680(v=vs.85).aspx) and use the WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW style to hide the window from the taskbar. Also, once you've created the window, call ShowWindow with SW_HIDE.

Answer (score -1):

I'd try to send them `WM_SETICON` with `NULL` for both the big and small icons.

Comment: This just affects the icon, which would essentially ask the taskbar to use a default icon. This won't hide the window from showing up on the taskbar.