# C++ don't display in the taskbar a window created with CreateWindow

Tags: c++, winapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Taskbar API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145510/windows-taskbar-api)
>   [Win32: How to hide 3rd party windows in taskbar by hWnd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219063/win32-how-to-hide-3rd-party-windows-in-taskbar-by-hwnd)

How can I prevent window from showing in the taskbar after I created it with CreateWindow? (Is there any parameter that allows me to do this, or something?)

Comment: @awoodland I disagree, the outcome is the same but the question is different, as is the answer.

Comment: @LiamM - I thought the answer addressed both cases with the quote from MSDN. The "possible duplicate" message just means it's been put up for a vote though.

Comment: @awoodland ah, fair enough, I'm not 100% on how this place works yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set 'dwStyle' to [`WS_POPUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles), the third argument:

```
HWND WINAPI CreateWindow(
    __in_opt  LPCTSTR lpClassName,
    __in_opt  LPCTSTR lpWindowName,
    __in      DWORD dwStyle,
    __in      int x,
    __in      int y,
    __in      int nWidth,
    __in      int nHeight,
    __in_opt  HWND hWndParent,
    __in_opt  HMENU hMenu,
    __in_opt  HINSTANCE hInstance,
    __in_opt  LPVOID lpParam);
```

If you're doing win32, I suggest, for your own sanity, you give [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) a try.

Answer (score 1):

[ITaskbarList::DeleteTab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will also remove a window from the taskbar.

Comment: Not always. When creating the window with WS_POPUP it works only on Win7.

Comment: Take my upvote. I have a scenario where I'm overlapping two windows (rendering some content on top-one & remaining on the bottom one) & this is best solution. `WS_POPUP` or any other style modification to the underlying window was not good.